# Feature request - Please add the ability to see who gave you an up or down vote

Tags: feature-request

And maybe require a reason for the vote.

Comment: This is a [fairly common concern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/135) with new users across the network. And it's perfectly understandable: what good is a downvote if you have no idea how to correct the problem? But I'd argue (and [have argued](http://jericson.github.io/2015/05/18/downvotes.html)) that downvotes are actually more productive as a form of criticism if they are anonymous and commenting is optional.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of voting is to provide a crowd-sourced ranking mechanism of questions and answers. Showing the identity of the voter may discourage honest voting based on the quality of the post and encourage the introjection of inter-personal favoritism and conflict into the voting apparatus. This has been suggested:

- [Revealing Identity of those who Vote Up or Down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139146/272257)

That  was closed as a duplicate of a prior question that explains that anonymous voting is [status-by-design](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-by-design).

- [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984/272257)

A requirement for comments to accompany down votes has also been discussed *ad nauseam* on the network.

- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/272257)

There is [now a reminder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/272257) shown to <2k users encouraging them to leave a comment if they have something helpful to say. The crowd-sourced powers-that-be on Meta.SE have determined that a requirement is not a good idea. The reasoning is [well summarized in a comment there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes#comment313_135) by a user who later acquired a lot of diamonds. Please contribute to the Meta.SE Q&A if you have something to add to this discussion.

Comment: Thank you Susan.

Comment: Interestingly, the 2k requirement to escape the DV reminder is the only reputation-based “privilege” I’m aware of that is not trumped by the ♦.